# There is no desktop only terminal ELEMENTARY OS FREYA

Tags: command-line

I installed elementary os now and first i tried to update it was slow so i did something else. When i came back to see it there was a black screen with down minus(idk what it is called). I rebooted My Laptop. But it opened without desktop there was only terminal. Please HELP!!

Comment: This site is only for Ubuntu questions; Elementary OS has its own StackExchange site. You can flag your post to ask a moderator to migrate it over there for you, but please do not cross-post.

Comment: If you have already asked on [elementaryos.se] consider asking on [unix.se], but your question in its current form is not of very high quality. A better description of the problem and a picture would be a good start.